# Unstable wi-fi latency

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, ping, latency

I'm having a strange latency problems with my network connection.

Here are results of pinging google's server, tough same goes for any remote server that allows ping.

```
C:\Users>ping -t -l 1000 8.8.8.8

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 1000 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=97ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=118ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=137ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=45ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=43ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=35ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=96ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=105ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=117ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=135ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=43ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=64ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=74ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=93ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=102ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=115ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=144ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=47ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=69ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=71ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=74ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=102ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=116ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=40ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=42ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=61ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=71ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=81ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=101ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=111ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=131ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=39ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=50ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=70ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=81ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=202ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=109ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=129ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=139ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=57ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=32ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=93ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=105ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=124ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=134ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=52ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=61ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=81ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=92ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=103ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=125ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=134ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=51ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=60ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=75ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=97ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=109ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=136ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=144ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=47ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=58ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=72ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=70ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=100ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=121ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=128ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=38ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=58ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=69ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=89ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=1000 time=97ms TTL=54

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 71, Received = 71, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 32ms, Maximum = 202ms, Average = 88ms
Control-C
```

I also noticed the increasing pattern that suddenly falls back to ~35ms & repeats regulary.

My laptop is Acer V 17 with Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4 wireless adapter. I tried updating driver to 12.0.0.230 version with no difference.

If I use wired PC, the average latency to 8.8.8.8 is 25ms with minimal deviation. Even pinging with my Android phone using the same wireless network the latency ranges from 25 to 35 ms. I even tried other laptop in the other room much further away from the router and it has stable 25ms with occasional lost packet due to distance likely.

When I ping the local gateway from the laptop using the wireless network it looks fairly normal:

```
C:\Users\David>ping -t -l 1000 10.0.0.138

Pinging 10.0.0.138 with 1000 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=3ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=7ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=4ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=3ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=4ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=14ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=11ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=9ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=5ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=7ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=7ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=8ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=7ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=3ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=8ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=7ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=7ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=8ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=7ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=5ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=71ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=11ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=4ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=8ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=7ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=5ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=9ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=8ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=7ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=7ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=15ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.138: bytes=1000 time=6ms TTL=255

Ping statistics for 10.0.0.138:
    Packets: Sent = 97, Received = 97, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 71ms, Average = 7ms
Control-C
```

My wi-fi router is Zyxel vmg1312 from the ISP, but as I said, the issue is exclusive to my laptop so far. I'm using Windows 10 build 10586 on both PC & laptop.

**Edit:** 
Tried connecting using wire - No issues. Shortly after connecting trough wi-fi again, it worked fine for a while, then it started oscillate again.

tried [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/is-qualcomm-atheros-ar9485-wireless-network/8c2fda54-c318-4282-879a-a100c91a7cbc?auth=1) solution, again works for a few pings then comes back:

```
C:\Users\David>ping -t 8.8.8.8

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=95ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=66ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=81ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=37ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=105ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=114ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=123ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=37ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=46ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=54ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=71ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=90ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=102ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=108ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=117ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=128ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=43ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=53ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=63ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=81ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=44ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=41ms TTL=54

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 32, Received = 32, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 21ms, Maximum = 128ms, Average = 64ms
Control-C
```

Exactly same thing happens when I reset `WlanSvc` service using task manager. It works for a while then comes back.

Comment: So what is your question? Your troubleshooting is sound, the problem is something with the laptop. Have you tried booting a live Linux distro and seeing if the problems are replicated, this would tell you whether it is hardware or software?

Comment: I tried booting Ubuntu 14.1 from DVD, but it could not even connect. There was no wireless adapter. I tried adding it, no luck. Do you have a better distro or way to make Wi-Fi work in live boot.

Comment: Current Ubuntu 16.04, Mint 18.0 (maybe 17.3?), Debian 8.0, Fedora 24, or other fairly recent distros should include the ath10k firmware/driver used by the Atheros QCA61x4 chipset.

Comment: Booted Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit from USB & it shows my wireless adapter as a wired connection, ofc not working. Cant even edit SSID / pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, it was a power managment settings. Anyone experiencing same issues, try going to `Control Panel -> Power managment -> schema settings (for the one selected) -> Advanced settings -> Wireless adapter` and change it to maximum performance.

I got localized windows so the path might not match exactly.